# How to automaticly run a specific class function everytime a new object of that class is created Python

Tags: python, class, oop

I want to know, how to run a class function/method everytime a new object of that class is created in Python. Let's say everytime we created a new object of a praticular class, the program is going to print "Hello, you just created a new object" . Thanks in advance

```
class question:
  def __init__(self):
    greeting(self)

  def greeting(self):
    print("Hello")

emg = question()
```

Comment: define the `__init__` method ?

Comment: put the code you want exectuted in the `__init__` method of the class.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist  ok , i tried to do that, but that does not help. I want to put this particular action inside a function, and i cant call it from inside that class object

Comment: Why can't you call it from within the class? WE might be able to help you better if we understood that.

Comment: @brunns thanks a lot the comment by the user butterflyknife has already helped me a lot to execute the fucntion from within the class it self. thanks a lots. cheers

Answer (score 2):

Put the code you want executed every time a new object is created in the **init** method:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hello, you just created a new object!")
        self.DoMoreComplicatedStuff()

    def DoMoreComplicatedStuff(self):
        print("I am doing more complicated stuff!")      

a = MyClass()
```

Comment: thanks @butterflyknife  , sorry for such a simple question, "sometimes it's darkest under the lamp." thanks a lot. cheers